# JSF and cloudControl

Tags: jsf, cloudcontrol

I'm learning Java EE and it appear to me that One of the things to Know is JSF

I'm also sing cloudControl but I haven't found a Way to Deploy a JSF Applications there.

Is there a way of deploying a JSF Applications on cloudControl ?

Comment: Although is not tested nor officially supported, you could try to deploy apps using tools like Mojarra[1] or MyFaces[2].

[1] https://javaserverfaces.java.net/
[2] http://myfaces.apache.org/

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment, you need to provide some implementation of JSF as a dependency together with embedded [jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-runner.html) or [tomcat](https://github.com/jsimone/webapp-runner) runner. Here you can find some example apps for [tomcat](https://github.com/cloudControl/java-spring-jsp-example-app/tree/tomcat_guide) and [jetty](https://github.com/cloudControl/java-spring-jsp-example-app/tree/jetty_guide). Maybe it would be also helpful for you to have a look on our existing [java guides](https://www.cloudcontrol.com/dev-center/Guides/Java).